# Como puedo capizalizar cadenas, ya sea con Java o JavaScript!?? Ayuda!

Tags: javascript, java, css, html5, jsp

Hola Buenos días a todos, lo que pasa es que quiero capitalizar unas cadenas ya sea con JavaScript, java o CSS, este ultimo con CSS ya lo intente con la propiedad text-transform: capitalize; y no dio resultado, solo cambian con las otras propiedades, por defecto, la aplicación arroja el resultado todas en Mayusculas por ejm: "JUAN JOSE" y lo que se espera obtener es: "Juan Jose" este es el codigo:

Este es el metodo que se encarga de arrojar el resultado a la vista:

```
public PersonAdapter personAPersonAdapter(Person persona){
        this.setLastName( persona.getLastName());
        this.setMotherLastName( persona.getMotherLastName());
        this.setName( persona.getName() );
        this.setBirthDate( persona.getBirthDate() );
        this.setNationality( persona.getcountry().getId() );
        this.setBirthPlace( persona.getExtendedData().getBirthPlace() );//Donde se pinta DF
        this.setSex( persona.getExtendedData().getSex() ); //Aqui es donde pinta el H "O" M
        this.setCurp( persona.getIdentityDocument()[0].getNumber()  );
        return this;
    }
```

Y a su vez, este es el JSP donde se muestra el resultado:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mbbn_mult_web_pub/css/afiNom/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mbbn_mult_web_pub/css/afiNom/datosRegistrados.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="XMY2147">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="titulo1" align="left">Llena los siguientes campos:</div>
    <div>
        <nav>
        <h3 align="center">Los datos que quedarán registrados son:</h3>
        <div class="content">

            <form:form commandName="persona">
                <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey"
                    value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
                <div id="contenedor">
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>Nombre:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <!-- <label>Diana Baez Dorantes</label> -->
                            <label style="text-transform: lowercase;">${persona.name} ${persona.motherLastName} ${persona.lastName}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <!-- <label>11-03-1980</label> -->
                            <label>${persona.birthDate}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>Lugar de nacimiento:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <!-- <label>Ciudad de México</label> -->
                            <label>${persona.birthPlace}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>G&eacute;nero:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <!-- <label>Femenino</label> -->
                            <label>${persona.sex}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>CURP:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <!-- <label>BADD110313HCMLNS09</label> -->
                            <label>${persona.curp}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>Correo electr&oacute;nico:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <!-- <label>diana_baez@gmail.com </label> -->
                            <label>${persona.email}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>Teléfono celular:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <!-- <label>5525608650</label> -->
                            <label>${persona.telefonoCelular}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>Fecha de operación:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <label>27-02-2017</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenidos">
                        <div id="columna1">
                            <label>Hora de operación:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="columna2">
                            <label>14:00:02</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="candadoStyle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="content1">
                    <div id="envioCodigo">
                        <div id="men_otp_1">
                            <p align="center">
                                Te hemos enviado un c&oacute;digo a tu celular. Tienes 5 minutos
                                para ingresarlo. Al momento de introducir el c&oacute;digo,
                                est&aacute;s aceptando que <strong>Bancomer</strong> te haga
                                llegar notificaciones al celular que acabas de proporcionar.
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div id="txtCodSeguridad" align="center">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">Ingresa código de seguridad:</td>
                                    <td width="330px"><input type="text" id="inputCodSeg"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class="lblReciCod">
                                <a>No recibí codigo de seguridad</a>
                                <!-- <label class="lblReciCod">No recibí codigo de seguridad</label> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input class="styleBotonCancel send" type="submit"
                        name="_eventId_cancel" value="Cancelar"> <input
                        class="styleBotonConfirm send" type="submit" name="_eventId_fin"
                        value="Confirmar">
                </div>
            </form:form>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ya por ultimo esta es la vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y me puedan apoyar en brindarme al algun ejm, de antemano les mando un cordial saludo

Answer (score 1):

Transformalas a lower todas y luego haz un replace de las primeras.

```js
var str = $(".myclass").text();
str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
$(".myclass").text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="myclass">JUAN JOSE</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, insisti con la respuesta de Einer y si acoplo perfectamente a mi caso, saludos cordiales

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando `substring`, obteniendo la primera letra del `string` y convertirla en mayúscula y concatenarle las demas:

```
public class StringUtils
{
    public static String captalize(String str)
    {
      return str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
 }

 StringUtils.captalize("hola mundo"); // Hola mundo
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta, en base al proyecto que puse, mas o menos como lo implementaría ya que en donde viaja la cadena se encuentra dentro de un objeto llamado "persona" :)

Comment: Puedes implementarlo en los setters del objeto `Persona`. Por ejemplo: public void `setName(String name) {  this._name = StringUtils.captalize(name); }` asi cuando lo obtengas, ya estara captalizado.

Comment: Asi fue como quedó;                                                                                                              
  public void setMotherLastName(String motherLastName) {
  this.motherLastName = StringUtils.captalize(motherLastName);
 }

Comment: Exacto, a eso me referia.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, de antemano te mando un cordial saludo

Comment: Pero te funciono?

Comment: Funciono perfectamente amigo :)

Comment: Excelente. Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si era lo que esperabas.

Comment: Listo, buena vibra hasta pronto :)

Comment: Hola nuevamente, espero y te encuentres bien, hoy vi que al hacer validaciones con mas de un nombre solo se capitaliza la primer letra del primer nombre y el segundo queda en minuscula algo como: "Juan jose", habria manera de corregir esto desde la misma funcion?? o se haria de otra manera?? Saludos